# Should a service indicate the usage of multi-factor authentication by a user for building trust?

Tags: multi-factor

We all know that MFA done right can greatly increase the security of an online identity.

There are services around with a fundamental trust problem among the users. For example online market places and classifieds. As long as the user accounts can be compromised via phishing, all indicators of authenticity are worthless.

Would the public indication of MFA usage for an account a valid measure to strengthen the trust relationship? Of course, some factors have to be taken into account (especially since MFA activation) as well:

- Duration of membership
- Amount of successful transactions
- Usage of a trusted (and consistent?) payment method

There's always the possibility that any user can go bad or that the fraud is planned long beforehand.

But are there any other major caveats? Do you think it is worth the effort?

Answer (score 1):

A service could **require** MFA for every user, but it shouldn't publicly disclose whether a user has it enabled or not.

Rather than giving users using MFA better reputation it would make users **not** using MFA easy targets – *low-hanging fruits*. They would be targeted first not only because there are less barriers without the MFA, but as not enabling MFA is also a possible indicator that the user may not take security that seriously. This could manifest, for example, as weak passwords or recycling the same password on several services. Additionally, they could be easier targets for social engineering.

Comment: `it would make users not using MFA easy targets` Do you mean targets against their identity like phishing? This is only true if an attacker can figure out the user ID for authentication. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I've elaborated on that a bit now.